# Keycloak register custom required action

Tags: keycloak

I've developed custom required action using `RequiredActionProvider` and `RequiredActionFactory`.
Then I've mounted the jar to the docker directory `/opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/deployments/`.
I can see in logs that action module is loaded and I can enable action in `Authentication > Required Actions > Register`

Is there way how to automatically enable that required action via cli (keycloak cli not rest api)?

Comment: Can you help with the sample code to create a custom action provider

Comment: Create some question for that and provide some sample somewhere in github and I can help you ;)

Answer (score 0):

You an do the following

1. Connect to the CLI using config credentials

   kcadm.sh config credentials --server http://localhost:8080/auth --realm master --user admin --client admin-cli --password password
2. Execute this command:

   kcadm.sh create authentication/register-required-action -r demorealm -b '{"providerId":"YOUR_REQUIRED_ACTION_PROVIDER_ID","name":"my required action"}'

The above will take the required action that you created and will register it using the name you provided in the command.

For future reference, if you're wondering which CLI command can be called and how, you can do the events trick. First enable the events for your realm including the user representation. Second execute the task in the UI. Third, check the events, you will then see which CLI was called.